# EditText and Focus in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, focus, listener

I need to insert a focus shift from one editText to another editText after a certain logic in my application.
example:
in a credit card number editText have a listener when the length of the value reaches 16 it skips to the expiration month editText ...

My code:

```
 numberCard.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(s.length()==16){
              
              //  how to make it jump to another editText?
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: I would like it to automatically jump to another editText when the length of the numberCard editText reaches 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your second *EditText* is `editText2` the you could do `ediText2.requestFocus()`

Comment: Always a pleasure to help. I think you should edit the title of you question to something related to "EditText" and "focus" so that it helps others who faced the similar problem.